# read text file and stop then how to continue at the last read point?

Tags: vb.net

I'm using vb.net 1.1 to develop the program.
I got text files that contain test result from a machine, like below.

T1      1.24535    2.56335    2.43253     1.24538    2.55619    4.35243 
T2      1.42542    1.63728    3.57295     4.59275    1.57320    2.72057 
T3      5.12857    2.45375    6.38593     2.58375    3.57259    3.57204 
.
.
.

I need to check the test result with the data from database, to find out which test result is failed. If there is a fail test result, I will show an alert to the operator and stop the checking process. Until the operator close the alert, then the checking process will continue from the last read point.

The problem that I'm facing is that I can't continue from the last read point.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use something like

[FileStream.Seek Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the Stream is not closed or modified while the operator is viewing the alert box, the current file position will remain the same (at "the last point read") and you won't have to do anything, except keep reading.

However if you close and reopen the stream during the time when the operator is looking at alerts then you'll have to seek your way back using [Seek method member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.seek(VS.80).aspx) or [Position property member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.position(VS.80).aspx). [System.IO.FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(VS.80).aspx) along with other kinds of streams inherit those members from the base [System.IO.Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream_members(VS.80).aspx) class.